# Shuffling a deck of cards

Tags: probability

If a card deck was shuffled, what is the probability that the $1$st card will be in the same order?

The answer I have is $\frac{1}{52!}$; is this correct?

Also, surely the answer is the same for the probability of the last card being in the same order?

Secondly, what is the probability that a KING will be amongst the initial $5$ cards?

Comment: What do you mean "the first card in same order"? Do you mean that the first card is the same before and after the shuffle?

Comment: For the second part, I would approach it by considering what is the probability that a king is not in the first 5 cards. That's quite easy to do ...

Comment: [Who is shuffling?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aeav3gVlAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By good shuffling **all** cards have equal probability to end up as first card of the deck after shuffling.

There are $52$ candidates and only one of them will indeed end up as first card of the deck after shuffling.

That leads to the conclusion that every card (so also the one that was first card before the shuffling) has probability $\frac1{52}$ to be the first card after shuffling.

Similar for last card.

---

Let $E_i$ denote the probability that the $i$-th card is not a king.

Then the probability that among the first $5$ cards there is no king equals:$$P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4\cap E_5)=$$$$P(E_1)P(E_2\mid E_1)P(E_3\mid E_1\cap E_2)P(E_4\mid E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)P(E_5\mid E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4)=$$$$\frac{48}{52}\frac{47}{51}\frac{46}{50}\frac{45}{49}\frac{44}{48}$$

So the probability that there is a king is among the first $5$ cards equals:$$1-\frac{48}{52}\frac{47}{51}\frac{46}{50}\frac{45}{49}\frac{44}{48}$$

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation. Could you please clarify further as to why the first fraction is (48/52) - why do you have 48?

Comment: There are $48$ cards that are no king. So the probability that the first card is no king is $\frac{48}{52}$.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question, I believe it would be $\frac{51!}{52!}=\frac{1}{52}$. If you fix the first card in the deck, there are 51! ways of rearranging the remaining cards, and 52! ways of arranging the entire deck, so that is the probability that a shuffle gives the first card in the same place. This assumes that all possible shuffles are equally likely. The result is true for fixing any card in the deck.